# Passing props through nested route reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that uses a custom router.

In my root App I have the following code (not the full code):

```
class ViewerApp extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact render={()=> <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>}/>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
        <TableRoute path='/table' exact component={TableView} bedData={this.state.bedData}/>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

The TableRoute component is as follows:

```
export const TableRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    authenticator.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} bedData={[]}/>
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/xxxx',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)
```

This line works fine, as well as the redirect. My problem is with passing bedData to the `<Component />`. I have checked with debugging and the  and the bedData is passed to the `Route` component inside the `TableRoute` class.

My final goal is to get the bedData as props into the `<TableView />` Component.

However, I cannot comprehend how to pass this as props to the `<Component />`. I have already tried as shown above with

```
<Component {...props} bedData={[]}/>
```

and with

```
<Component {...props} />
```

as I thought it should get passed with the direct props, but nothing worked. i am quite new to React too, so this could be newbie stupidity too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like a great time to introduce a flux store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `bedData` to your custom Route which is accessable in custom Route as `rest.bedData` which you can pass on to your components like this

```
export const TableRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
     authenticator.isAuthenticated === true
  ? <Component {...props} bedData={rest.bedData}/>
  : <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/xxxx',
      state: { from: props.location }
    }} />
 )} />
)
```